# Knight or Knave

Tags: logical-deduction, liars

On the island of knights and knaves (where knights always tell the truth and knaves lie), you meet two islanders named Penny and Quinru.

> Penny: Both Quinru and I are knaves!

Who is a knight and who is a knave?
[Question Source](https://brilliant.org/practice/knights-and-formal-logic/?p=1)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

They are

> Penny is a knave
>  Quinru is a knight

Because

> if Penny were a knight then it is true Penny is a knave.  a Contradiction.  so Penny is a knave.  Therefore it is false that Penny is a knave AND Quinru is a knave.  Therefore Quinru must be a knight

Comment: The real complication here: Why would I trust them to tell me their names? What we actually know is that the one who spoke is a Knave and the other one is either not a Knave or not named Quinru. It could be a mildly interesting puzzle if we knew where that information came from.